Regras de negócios no SQL
Sou estudante de Ads, to aprendendo programação e sou estagiária numa empresa multinacional... Minha dúvida é a seguinte, é comum as empresas usarem ainda hoje, regras de negócios dentro do banco de dados? Tipo, tudo do site vir de procedures e não estar no código?
Quando entrei, me falaram que era usado C# lá, eu estudei muito essa linguagem desde que iniciei o estágio mas eu não consigo entender a forma como é feito lá. Todo erro, tem que analisar a proc e não o código necessariamente, sabe? Basicamente a gente usa o código pra ver em qual banco a query é chamada e a programação mesmo das regras são no banco, tem que programar no SQL
E como sou nova na área, não sei se é uma prática comum ou padrão da empresa.

Esse tipo de pergunta talvez esteja fora do escopo da comunidade (não tenho certeza). Sugiro tentar buscar opiniões no chat: https://chat.stackexchange.com/?tab=site&host=pt.stackoverflow.com

Não é muito comum, porém algumas empresas tem uma quantidade enorme de dados para serem processados, que podem performar melhor em banco de dados e a migração de disso para outro formato seria muito custoso. Trabalhei por muito tempo em uma empresa que operava desta forma, o conhecimento que adquiri lá não foi muito util em outras empresas que utilizavam programação orientada a objetos. Não sei se respondeu a sua pergunta.
